# Android:How to access MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI to read data in Cursor without using any permissions

Tags: android, permissions

Usually, when we use code to obtain album data, we need to register the permission "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" to run the following code:

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null,
                     null, null, null);
```

But I don't need to read the file, the cursor will be empty if no permissions are used

Is there a way to read the data without any permission?

Use the following code to open the image picker to select a picture without any permissions,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");
intent.startForResult(it,code);
```

but the returned picture url needs permission to access

here is the code

```
Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(picUrl,
                            null, null, null, null);
       cursor.moveToFirst();

       String filePath="";
       Uri picUri=selectedImage;
      try{

                         int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
                        filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                        Uri baseUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media");
                        picUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(baseUri, "" + id);
                    }catch (Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    ContentResolver contentResolver = activity.getContentResolver();

      try {
         InputStream inStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(picUri);

         final byte[] file = PicUtils.readFileBytes(inStream);
```

Comment: No. The returned picture url does not need any permission to access. ACTION_PICK does not need permissions.

Comment: @blackapps But reading the image file of this url requires permission in some mobiles

Comment: No. As said before: no permission required.  Show your code. And mention which devices. You keep all too vague.

Comment: @blackapps Code has updated,  The device model  is Google pixel 4XL, Android 13

Comment: Completely wrong code. You convert a nice uri, a content scheme, to a file system path using column .DATA. You have no access to that file system path. You should use the uri directly like you do with  InputStream inStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(picUri);. Remove that other code.

Comment: @blackapps It worked ,tks